# Groupby and A)Concate matching strings(and or substring) B)Sum the values

Tags: pandas, pattern-matching, pandas-groupby, string-concatenation

**I have df:**

```
row_numbers    ID     code        amount
   1           med    a           1
   2           med    a, b        1
   3           med    b, c        1
   4           med    c           1
   5           med    d           10
   6           cad    a, b        1 
   7           cad    a, b, d     0
   8           cad    e           2
```

Pasted the above df:

[image]

I wanted to do groupby on column-**ID** and A)Combine the strings if substring/string matches(on column-**code**) B)sum the values of column-**amount**.

**Expected results:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

column-**row_numbers** has no role here in df. I just took here to explain the output.

A)grouping on column-**ID** and looking at column-**code**, row1 string i.e., a is matching with row2's sub string. row2's substring i.e., b is matching with row3's substring. row3's substring i.e., c is matching with string of row4 and Hence combining row1, row2, row3 and row4. row5 string is not matching with any of string/substring so it is separate group. B) Based on this adding row1, row2, row3 and row4 values. and row5 as separate group.

Thanks in advance for your time and thoughts:).

**EDIT - 1**

Pasting the real time.

[image]

**Expected output:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

have to do on grouping column-**id** and concatenating the values of column-**code** and summing the values of column-**units** and **vol**. It is color coded the matching(to be contacted) values of column-**code**. row1 has link with row5 and row9. row9 has inturn link with row3. Hence combining row1, row5, row9, row3. Simliarly row2 and row7 and so on. row8 has no link with any of the values with-in group-med(column-id) and hence will be as separate row.

Thanks!.

Comment: What code do you have now, what does it do and how is that different from your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: From your latest sample data, this is not a simple data munging. There is no vectorized solution. It relates to [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory). You need to find [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) within each group of `ID` and do the calculation on each connected components.

Consider each string as a `node` of graph. If 2 strings are overlapped, they are connected nodes. For every `node`, you need to traverse all paths connected to it. Do calculation on all connected nodes through these paths. This traversal can be done by using [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) logic.

However, before processing depth-first search, you need to preprocess strings to `set` to check overlapping.

**Method 1: Recursive**

Do the following:

- Define a function `dfs` to recursively run depth-first search
- Define a function `gfunc` to use with groupby `apply`. This function will traverse elements of each group of `ID` and return the desired dataframe.
- Get rid of any blank spaces in each string and split and convert them
  to sets using `replace`, `split` and `map`  and assign it to a new column `new_code` to `df`
- Call groupby on `ID` and `apply` using function `gfunc`. Call `droplevel` and `reset_index` to get the desired output

Codes as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def dfs(node, index, glist, g_checked_rows):        
    ret_arr = df.loc[index, ['code', 'amount', 'volume']].values
    g_checked_rows.add(index)   
    for j, s in glist:
        if j not in g_checked_rows and not node.isdisjoint(s):      
            t_arr = dfs(s, j, glist, g_checked_rows)
            ret_arr[0]  += ', ' + t_arr[0]
            ret_arr[1:] += t_arr[1:]

    return ret_arr

def gfunc(x):   
    checked_rows = set()    
    final = []  
    code_list = list(x.new_code.items())
    for i, row in code_list:
        if i not in checked_rows:       
            final.append(dfs(row, i, code_list, checked_rows))

    return pd.DataFrame(final, columns=['code','units','vol'])

df['new_code'] = df.code.str.replace(' ','').str.split(',').map(set)
df_final = df.groupby('ID', sort=False).apply(gfunc).droplevel(1).reset_index()

Out[16]:
    ID                                        code  units  vol
0  med  CO-96, CO-B15, CO-B15, CO-96, OA-18, OA-18      4    4
1  med                        CO-16, CO-B20, CO-16      3    3
2  med                       CO-252, CO-252, CO-45      3    3
3  med                                      OA-258      1    1
4  cad                        PR-96, PR-96, CO-243      4    4
5  cad                        PR-87, OA-258, PR-87      3    3
```

---

Note: I assume your pandas version is 0.24+. If it is < 0.24, the last step you need to use `reset_index` and `drop` instead of `droplevel` and `reset_index` as follows

```
df_final = df.groupby('ID', sort=False).apply(gfunc).reset_index().drop('level_1', 1)
```

---

**Method 2: Iterative**

To make this complete, I implement a version of `gfunc` using iterative process instead of recursive. Iterative process requires only one function.
However, the function is more complicated. The logic of iterative process as follows

1. push the first node to `deque`. Check if `deque` not empty, pop the top node out.
2. if a node is not marked `checked`, process it and mark it as   `checked`
3. find all its neighbors in the reverse order of list of nodes that
   haven't been marked, push them to the `deque`
4. Check if `deque` not empty, pop out a node from the top `deque` and
   process from step 2

Code as follows:

```
def gfunc_iter(x):  
    checked_rows = set()    
    final = []  
    q = deque() 
    code_list = list(x.new_code.items())
    code_list_rev = code_list[::-1]
    for i, row in code_list:
        if i not in checked_rows:           
            q.append((i, row))
            ret_arr = np.array(['', 0, 0], dtype='O')
            while (q):
                n, node = q.pop()
                if n in  checked_rows:
                    continue                
                ret_arr_child = df.loc[n, ['code', 'amount', 'volume']].values
                if not ret_arr[0]:
                    ret_arr = ret_arr_child.copy()
                else:
                    ret_arr[0]  += ', ' + ret_arr_child[0]
                    ret_arr[1:] += ret_arr_child[1:]                    
                checked_rows.add(n)         
                #push to `q` all neighbors in the reversed list of nodes    
                for j, s in code_list_rev: 
                    if j not in checked_rows and not node.isdisjoint(s):
                        q.append((j, s))
            final.append(ret_arr)

    return pd.DataFrame(final, columns=['code','units','vol'])

df['new_code'] = df.code.str.replace(' ','').str.split(',').map(set)
df_final = df.groupby('ID', sort=False).apply(gfunc_iter).droplevel(1).reset_index()
```

Comment: `@ Andy`
Thank you very much for your time.
If the values in column-**code** are not sorted then the above code is not working. In my actual data I cannot sort on column-**code**, because value(substrings) includes characters and that I cant break(or do anything). I verified the code by exchanging the row4 and row5 values. Please suggest the change

Comment: @RaghavendraS. I edited the answer to fix that issue. The modification is only in `gfunc`. I also add `row9` to the sample to test cases of multiple disjoints per `ID`.

Comment: `@Andy` I have run the data over edited code and I didn't get the expected results. Felt like it was close and I don't know where it is breaking. I have also edited the data and output again. Please refer details of Edit-1. And please let me know your thoughts. We can connect through chat if it requires after 10PM IST today. Thanks you very much.

Comment: @RaghavendraS: base on your latest sample, your problem relates to graph theory. I revised the answer to address it. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Andy. Code is giving expected results:)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the three main ideas for executing what you want are:

1. create an accumulator datastructure ( a DataFrame in this case)
2. iterate over a pair of rows, in each iteration you have (currentRow, nextRow)
3. pattern matching of current row in next row and pattern matching in the accumulated rows

It's not totally clear the exactly pattern match you're looking for, so I assumed that if any letter of currentRow code is on the next one, then concatenate them.

using a data.csv (with espace separators) as example:

```
row_numbers ID code amount
1 med a 1
2 med a,b 1
3 med b,c 1
4 med c 1
5 med d 10
6 cad a,b 1
7 cad a,b,d 0
8 cad e 2
```

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import zip_longest

def generate_pairs(group):    
    ''' generate pairs (currentRow, nextRow) '''
    group_curriterrows = group.iterrows()
    group_nextiterrows = group.iterrows()
    group_nextiterrows.__next__()
    zip_list = zip_longest(group_curriterrows, group_nextiterrows) 
    return zip_list

def generate_lists_to_check(currRow, nextRow, accumulated_rows):
    ''' generate list if any next letters are in current ones and
    another list if any next letters are in the accumulated codes '''
    currLetters = str(currRow["code"]).split(",")
    nextLetters = str(nextRow["code"]).split(",")
    letter_inNext = [letter in nextLetters for letter in currLetters]
    unique_acc_codes = [str(v) for v in accumulated_rows["code"].unique()]
    letter_inHistory = [any(letter in unq for letter in nextLetters) 
                                           for unq in unique_acc_codes]
    return letter_inNext, letter_inHistory

def create_newRow(accumulated_rows, nextRow):
  nextRow["row_numbers"] = str(nextRow["row_numbers"])
  accumulated_rows = accumulated_rows.append(nextRow,ignore_index=True)
  return accumulated_rows

def update_existingRow(accumulated_rows, match_idx, Row):
  accumulated_rows.loc[match_idx]["code"] += ","+Row["code"]
  accumulated_rows.loc[match_idx]["amount"] += Row["amount"]
  accumulated_rows.loc[match_idx]["volume"] += Row["volume"]
  accumulated_rows.loc[match_idx]["row_numbers"] += ','+str(Row["row_numbers"])
  return accumulated_rows

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_csv("extended.tsv",sep=" ")
    groups = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns) 
    for ID, group in df.groupby(["ID"], sort=False):
        accumulated_rows = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
        group_firstRow = group.iloc[0]
        accumulated_rows.loc[len(accumulated_rows)] = group_firstRow.values 
        row_numbers = str(group_firstRow.values[0])
        accumulated_rows.set_value(0,'row_numbers',row_numbers) 
        zip_list = generate_pairs(group)
        for (currRow_idx, currRow), Next  in zip_list:
            if not (Next is None):
                (nextRow_idx, nextRow) = Next
                letter_inNext, letter_inHistory = \
                        generate_lists_to_check(currRow, nextRow, accumulated_rows) 

                if any(letter_inNext) :
                  accumulated_rows = update_existingRow(accumulated_rows, (len(accumulated_rows)-1), nextRow) 
                elif any(letter_inHistory):
                  matches = [ idx for (idx, bool_val) in enumerate(letter_inHistory) if bool_val == True ]
                  first_match_idx = matches[0]
                  accumulated_rows = update_existingRow(accumulated_rows, first_match_idx, nextRow)
                  for match_idx in matches[1:]:
                      accumulated_rows = update_existingRow(accumulated_rows, first_match_idx, accumulated_rows.loc[match_idx])
                      accumulated_rows = accumulated_rows.drop(match_idx) 

                elif not any(letter_inNext):
                  accumulated_rows = create_newRow(accumulated_rows, nextRow)
        groups = groups.append(accumulated_rows)
    groups.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
    print(groups)
```

OUTPUT normal rows order REMOVING lines using column volume from current code because first exampe has no column volume:

```
  row_numbers   ID         code amount
0           1  med  a,a,b,b,c,c      4
1           5  med            d     10
2           6  cad    a,b,a,b,d      1
3           8  cad            e      2
```

OUTPUT new example:

```
  row_numbers   ID                                   code amount volume
0     1,5,9,3  med  CO-96,CO-B15,CO-B15,CO-96,OA-18,OA-18      4      4
1         2,7  med                     CO-16,CO-B20,CO-16      3      3
2         4,6  med                    CO-252,CO-252,CO-45      3      3
3           8  med                                 OA-258      1      1
4       10,13  cad                     PR-96,PR-96,CO-243      4      4
5       11,12  cad                     PR-87,OA-258,PR-87      3      3
```

Comment: `@ Bernardo` Thank you very much for your time. If the values in column-**code** are not sorted then the above code is not working. In my actual data I cannot sort on column-**code**, because value(substrings) includes characters and that I cant break(or do anything). I verified the code by exchanging the row4 and row5 values.  Please suggest the change

Comment: @ Raghavendra,  what's the expected output from this new data ?  When we change rows 4 and 5, the code 'a, b' doesn't have any match in 'c' so the get separated after that 'c' matches with 'b,c' so they get together... it's making sense to me.

Comment: @RaghavendraS I updated my solution, check if this suits you. the new idea is both check previous row, if code is not there, check if code is in unique accumulated codes

Comment: `@Bernardo` Thanks again for the response. I am not able to catch all the lines of code. And I run the code on real time data, I didnt get the correct result. Let me put  what it is expected this way: A) on column-**ID** should be grouped. B) with in this group I have to club the links of substrings in the grouped rows. Example: a from row1 has link with row2, this row2 in-turn has link with row3 by means of substring-b. row3 has link with row4 by means of substring-4 and row5 dont have link with any other row. Thus row1,row2,row3,row4 will get grouped & row5(d) will be treated separately

Comment: `@Bernardo`. Please let me know your free time to discuss if it requires. And I will be free from 6.30AM to 11.30PM IST. ...Thanks you

Comment: You said the example exchanging rows 4 and 5 was not working with the first code. Is the current code for that example output not the correct one as well ? could you edit the expected output for this one

I refactored the code so it should be easily reused and declarative. 

inside the function "generate_lists_to_check"  we have the line "letter_inNext = [letter in currLetters for letter in nextLetters]" which it was supposed to do what you mention in your example -> for every letter in row1 check if they are in the letters in row2. if any letter in row1 is in row2 concatenate them.

Comment: @RaghavendraS please check the stackoverflow chat, we can discuss further about the solution in there.

Comment: `@Bernardo` Yes, with the second edit also I didnt get the results. I have edited the data and output again. Please refer details of Edit-1. And please let me know your thoughts. We can connect through chat after 10PM IST today if it requires. Thank you.

Comment: `@Bernardo` I run the edited code over the same data which I pasted in the EDIT-1. Code is giving row3 separately but I according to requirement it should be clubbed along with row1, row5 and row9. Because row1 has link with row5 and row9. row9 has inturn link with row3. Hence it should be row1, row5, row9, row3 combined together. Thanks.

Comment: @RaghavendraS, I just copied the code from my current answer with the data from EDIT1 and I got the output you expected in the EDITED1 example

Comment: I updated my code to show the rows that were concatenated.... Could you  try running this code and confirm ? It seems to be working exactly as you described for me , rows 1,5,9,3 are indeed together